# how to upload data to storage account from CICD?

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-blob-storage

We need to save the "artifacts" from the build/release pipeline. How do we upload some data into  a storage account from the deployment pipeline?

For exaample, here is my data:

```
{"mydata":"some stuff"}
```

I'd like to upload this into mystorageaccount/mystoragecontainer/fea8e047-0dc4-4f96-8499-aee5c3929be3.json.

**How do we create blobs from the CICD pipeline?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tested in my environment

I created build and release pipelines to copy data to the Azure Blob Storage

I followed these steps :

I created a file in a folder in Azure Repos

[image]

Now, I created a build pipeline with two tasks: Copy Files, Publish Artifact

I configured Copy Files task to copy files from the folder I created in the Azure Repos to Azure Artifacts

[image]

I configured Publish Artifact task to publish the Artifact data to Azure Pipelines

[image]

Now I ran the pipeline and the files in the folder got copied to the Artifact and the Artifact data is published to the Azure Pipelines

[image]

Now, I created a release pipeline with task as Azure File Copy to deploy the artifact data to Azure Blob Storage

[image]

I configured the Azure File Copy task with version 3.0, source as the artifact data, Destination Type as Azure Blob, Azure Service connection, storage account and the container names

[image]

Now I ran the release pipeline, and the file is created in the Azure Blob Storage

[image]

[image]